# Can't install RMagick 4.2.6 on MacOS BigSur

Tags: ruby, imagemagick, rmagick, pkg-config

Whenever I try to install rmagick I get `ERROR: Can't install RMagick 4.2.6. Can't find ImageMagick with pkg-config`. I tried all the other options, with installing `imagemagick@6`, setting `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`, unlinking, reinstalling & linking imagemagick, setting the pkg-config path from the lib folder of imagemagick, nothing worked.

More detailed error:

```
checking for brew... yes
checking for Ruby version >= 2.3.0... yes
checking for pkg-config... yes


ERROR: Can't install RMagick 4.2.6. Can't find ImageMagick with pkg-config


*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
```

Answer (score 1):

I used to get an error and also the rmagick installation issue:

```
pkg-config --list-all
[1]    664 segmentation fault  pkg-config --list-all
```

pkg-config has version 0.29.2, I tried both removing the `proj.pc` file and changing it to the details from [this comment](https://github.com/OSGeo/PROJ/issues/2064#issuecomment-598439532).

`pkg-config --exists --print-errors "proj"` even returns nothing, so I don't think there's an error on that side.

I managed to fix the issue by uninstall highway (`brew uninstall highway`), because it has a conflict over a variable. Running `pkg-config --debug --list-all` will show that.

Comment: Uninstalling `highway` fixed this for me too, unsure if there are any side effects to doing this.

Comment: Can you share the content of `libhwy-test.pc`? I suspect there is something in that file that is causing this segfault.

Comment: It seems like I don't even have that file in the `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig` folder. Although I did remove highway already, I don't think that action should've removed the file though